# Reverse DNS in bind 9 failed and VPS

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, bind, ptr-record

My Ip address is `1.2.3.4` (single ip for mail and dns server) and my domain name is example.com, I use Centos 7 and bind 9
output of  command:

```
`host 1.2.3.4`
```

is:

```
`Host 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`
```

My `/etc/named.zones` is:

```
    zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/example.com.zone";
    allow-query { any; };
    allow-transfer { slaves; };
};

zone "3.2.1.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    notify no;
    file "/var/named/example.com.ptr.zone";
    allow-query { any; };
    allow-transfer { slaves; };
};
```

and `/var/named/example.com.zone` is:

```
; Zone file for example.com
@ 100 IN SOA ns1.example.com. admin.example.com. (
2015052700 ; serial, todays date+todays
28800 ; refresh, seconds
7200 ; retry, seconds
2419200 ; expire, seconds
86400 ) ; minimum, seconds

; DEFINE NS RECORDS
example.com. 100 IN NS ns1.example.com.
example.com. 100 IN NS ns2.example.com.

; A RECORDS
ns1.example.com. 100 IN A  1.2.3.4
ns2.example.com. 100 IN A  1.2.3.4
example.com. 100 IN A  1.2.3.4
mail.example.com. 100 IN A 1.2.3.4

; MX RECORDS
example.com. 100 IN MX 0 mail.example.com.

; CNAME RECORDS
imap 100 IN CNAME mail.example.com.
smtp 100 IN CNAME mail.example.com.
www.example.com. IN CNAME example.com.

; TXT/SPF RECORDS
example.com. 14000 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ~all"
example.com. 14000 IN SPF "v=spf1 a mx ~all"
```

and `/var/named/example.com.ptr.zone` is:

```
$TTL 3D
@       IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. example.com. (
                        2015090900 ; Serial, todays date + todays serial
                        6H      ; Refresh
                        1H      ; Retry
                        1W      ; Expire
                        1D)     ; Minimum TTL
        IN       NS      ns1.example.com.
        IN       NS      ns2.example.com.

$ORIGIN 3.2.1.in-addr.arpa.
4     PTR     ns1.example.com.
4     PTR     www.example.com.
4     PTR     example.com.
```

I have VPS, forward DNS work perfectly but reverse DNS didn't work, gmail detect my emails as spam, what is wrong?
Also I start `named` service and `named-chroot` service, is it wrong?

Comment: As Anthony Geoghegan said, your VPS's ISP should do this. Also please not you can not have duplicate records under 3.2.1.in-addr.arpa. In the above example you have 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, the reverse DNS of a virtual private server (VPS) is managed by the Internet hosting service. They administer the PTR records for the network block of IP addresses that have been assigned to them by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) and it would be unusual for them  to delegate management of DNS PTR zones to customers.

You should ask your hosting provider to configure the PTR record for your IP
address. Alternatively, many hosting services provide a control panel to allow the customer to do configure it themselves.

Comment: I ask them but they can't setup reverse dns for my domain name, because I'm in Iran with .ir domains and VPS hosted in USA .

Comment: I presume that's for political reasons beyond their control. That sucks! Maybe you'd have more luck with a European provider. FWIW, I use hetzner.de who provide an easy-to-use control panel for configuring the PTR record.

Answer (score 4):

Contact your hosting provider.
They need to setup your PTR Record.